# XDocument.Descendents is not case-sensitive

Tags: xml, vb.net

I thought XML was case-sensitive? I am looking at XML files to find a field which will either be < Header > or < header >. I use the following code:

```
If Not xmlDoc.Descendants("Header") Is Nothing Then
    do something
ElseIf Not xmlDoc.Descendants("header") Is Nothing Then
    do something else
Else
    Print(1, "No header information found" & vbCrLf)
    messageText.Text = "Validation Complete"
    Return false
End If
```

So I am looking at an XML file that has < header > and the 'do something' line is being run! How can I make this a case-sensitive thingymabob?

Answer (score 0):

[`XDocument.Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *is* case sensitive, but it will not return `Nothing` when no matching elements are found - it will return an `IEnumerable(Of XElement)` with no elements.  So, you could rewrite your logic something like this:

```vb
If xmlDoc.Descendants("Header").Any() Then
    ' do something - <Header> found
ElseIf xmlDoc.Descendants("header").Any() Then
    ' do something else - <header> found
Else
    Print(1, "No header information found" & vbCrLf)
    messageText.Text = "Validation Complete"
    Return false
End If
```

You could also use VB.NET's support for XML literals, which I find a little more readable:

```vb
If xmlDoc...<Header>.Any() Then
    ' do something - <Header> found
ElseIf xmlDoc...<header>.Any() Then
    ' do something else - <header> found
Else
    '...
End If
```